# windows variable is not defined when in server

Tags: javascript, html, css

I've this code in a .html file

```
<script type="text/javascript">    
$(window).scroll(function(event) {
    $("#idTimelineLeft").css("margin-top", 0-$(document).scrollTop());
});
</script>
```

In a local machine the code (block the horizontal scrolling of a div) it works great, but when I put in a server it gives this error :

> Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined

I've searched for a solution but until now, no success :(

Thank you !

Comment: looks like you want to use `jquery`. Do you have jquery installed ?

Comment: Didn't see it before !
The loading of the jquery was giving an error (it should be https and not http)
Many thanks ! :)